# What adavantages does HQL have over SQL for Group By queries

Tags: sql, nhibernate, hibernate, hql

I am concentrating this question on 'reporting-type' queries (count, avg etc. i.e. ones that don't return the domain model itself) and I was just wondering if there is any inherent performance benefit in using HQL, as it may be able to leverage the second level cache. Or perhaps even better - cache the entire query.

The obvious implied benefit is that NHibernate knows what the column names are as it already knows about the model mapping.

Any other benefits I should be aware of?

*[I am using NHibernate but I assume that in this instance what applies to Hibernate will be equally applicable to NHibernate]*

Answer (score 2):

There are zero advantages.  HQL will not outperform a direct database query to perform data aggregation and computation. 
The result of something like:

```
Select count(*), dept from employees group by dept
```

Will always perform faster at the DB then in HQL.  Note I say *always* because it is lame to take the 'depends on your situation' line of thinking.  If it has to do with data and data aggregation; do it in SQL.

Comment: Actually .. do you know what HQL is ? The select you gave written in HQL will just issue back the same SQL you gave . It's not doing it in memory !

Comment: HQL queries like

select avg(cat.weight), sum(cat.weight), max(cat.weight), count(cat) from Cat cat 

will not receive any performance 'advantages' over 'raw SQL'.  The performance advantages 'hoped' for in the question will not materialize.  That is the focus of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The objects in the second level cache are only retrieved by id, so Hibernate will always run a query to obtain a list of ids and then read those objects either from the second-level cache or with another query.

On the other hand, Hibernate can cache the query and avoid the DB call completely in some situations. However you have to consider that a change to any of the tables involved in the query will invalidate it, so you might not hit the cache very often. See [here](https://wiki.dgfoundation.org/display/DRD/2.+Guidelines+about+using+query+caching) a description of how the query-cache works.

So the cost of your query is either 0, if the query is cached, or about the same as doing the query in straight SQL. Depending on how often your data changes you might save a lot by enabling query caching or you might not save anything.

If you have a high volume of queries and you can tolerate stale results, I'd say it's a lot better to use another cache for the query results that only expires every x minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The only advantage i can think of is that ORM queries are typically cached at the (prepared) statement level, so if you do the same query lots of times chances are you are reusing a prepared statement.

But since you asked specifically for **reporting queries and performance**, I cannot think of any **practical** advantages (I'm glossing over the fact that you have other advantages like data-access consistency, ORM querying vs SQL (most of the times it's easier to write a query with HQL), data-type conversions, etc )

Answer (score -4):

HQL is an object query language. SQL is a relational query language.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Now would you like to try answering the actual question.

Comment: For reports, you may want to use SQL.